# Finding Count of Occurrences & Time Gap between a Timeline in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a Table, like the below, which has a timeline and values (like YES/NO) that are coming from different sensors. How do I do the following:

How many times there has a been a flip-flops (for YES to NO or NO to YES), in the below example it has happened 2 times.

```
1 , A0001, NO,  2017-06-14 02:03:26.0
2 , A0001, NO,  2017-06-14 02:03:26.0
3 , A0001, YES, 2017-06-14 02:03:26.0
4 , A0001, NO,  2017-06-14 02:03:26.0
5 , A0001, YES, 2017-06-14 02:03:26.0
6 , A0001, NO , 2017-06-14 02:03:26.0
```

Comment: To clarify: There have been two changes from 'NO' to 'YES', *and* two changes from 'YES' to 'NO'. That's a total of 4 changes. Are you only interested in changes in 1 direction, or perhaps only interested in round trips ('NO' => 'YES' => 'NO'). Also, are all sensors binary, or could some changes involve more than two possible values? Sample desired output, showing handling for more than two possible values if relevant, would help some.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on version 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select count(distinct grp) from (
    select row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col3) 
         - row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) as grp
    from t
) as tt;
```

As RDFozz suggests in his comment, there are actually four changes

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7632c48ceadbbd82c6200362f1965278)

Answer (score 0):

Using Sql Server,

```
declare @t table(id int,col1 varchar(30), col2 varchar(30),col3 datetime)
insert into @t (id,col1,col2,col3) VALUES 
(1 , 'A0001' , 'NO',  '2017-06-14 02:03:26.0') 
,(2 , 'A0001' , 'NO', '2017-06-15 02:03:26.0') 
,(3 , 'A0001' , 'YES','2017-06-16 02:03:26.0') 
,(4 , 'A0001' , 'NO', '2017-06-17 02:03:26.0') 
,(5 , 'A0001' , 'YES','2017-06-18 02:03:26.0') 
,(6 , 'A0001',  'NO' ,'2017-06-19 02:03:26.0') 

;With CTE1 as
(
select *
,ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION by col1 order by col3)rn from @t
)

, cte
AS (
    SELECT
        rn
        ,col1
        ,col2
        ,col3
        ,0 changecount
    FROM cte1
    where rn=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        t.rn
        ,t.col1
        ,t.col2
        ,t.col3
        ,CASE 
            WHEN t.col2 <> t1.col2
                THEN changecount + 1
            ELSE changecount
            END
    FROM cte1 t
    INNER JOIN cte t1 ON t.col1 = t1.col1
        AND t.rn = t1.rn + 1
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Comment: How does this answer OP if you're using `sql server` and the question is tagged for `MySQL` ?